How to convert ML model to an Android App?
I want to create a simple mobile application that detects the dialect language that the user input in. Fortunately i think my back end works as i test URL given by pycharm in Postman to test the output and thankfully postman able to predict the dialect language that the user input in.
Challenge:
I really tried to give the same output that i got in postman in my android studio mobile application. But it is unfortunate im getting the same error message. java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.:***
this is my android studio code MainActivity:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText inputuser;
    Button detectnow;
    TextView result;
    String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/predict";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        inputuser = findViewById(R.id.input);
        detectnow = findViewById(R.id.translate);
        result = findViewById(R.id.result);

        detectnow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Get the user input text
                String userInput = inputuser.getText().toString();

                // Create JSON object with the user input
                JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonBody.put("text", userInput);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Create a request queue
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

                // Create a JSON object request
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try {
                                    // Get the predicted dialect from the response
                                    String predictedDialect = response.getString("predicted_dialect");

                                    // Set the predicted dialect to the result TextView
                                    result.setText("Predicted Dialect: " + predictedDialect);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                // Handle errors
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                // Add the request to the request queue
                queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}

this is my backend python coding:
    from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load the dataset and preprocess it
df_dialect = pd.read_csv("dialect_list_balance.csv").dropna()
le = LabelEncoder()
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
bag = vectorizer.fit_transform(df_dialect['sentence'])
features = bag.toarray()
vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
df_bow = pd.DataFrame(features, columns=vocab)
df_bow['dialect_class'] = le.fit_transform(df_dialect['dialect'])

# Train the model
X = df_bow.iloc[:, :-1]
y = df_bow['dialect_class']
gb_clf = GradientBoostingClassifier()
gb_clf.fit(X, y)


@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    # Get the input text from the request body
    input_text = request.json.get('text')

    # Preprocess the input text
    input_bag = vectorizer.transform([input_text])
    input_features = input_bag.toarray()

    # Predict the dialect of the input text
    prediction = gb_clf.predict(input_features)

    # Decode the predicted label to dialect class
    predicted_dialect = le.inverse_transform(prediction)[0]

    # Return the predicted dialect as a JSON response
    return jsonify({"predicted_dialect": predicted_dialect})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080)

Solutions that i tried and did not work:
Latest update is i tried to change the String URL in MainActivity to my ipv4 config! but then the error disappeared but my mobile application just exit from the virtual emulator. I dont think this is because of my device performance as it runs in recommended 16GB RAM. Now im stuck again
Flush your DNS
Connect with the specified port
go through browser settings
turn off firewall
chatgpt
solutions that i search up
Youtube video that i refer to do this project

Unclear if seen: How to connect to my http://localhost web server from Android Emulator

omg it works like a charm... predicted dialect is kedah i got it ! thanks!!
